# Where clause and truncating decimal points

Tags: mysql

Values in my table have a number of decimal points:

```
20.828292
21.9292992
...
```

I need to query the table to find results that match but to only 1 decimal place.

So where 20.8 would match the 20.828292.

Can I do this with SQL? How?

Comment: you can use `TRUNCATE` function of mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like

```
select * from table where TRUNCATE(attribute,1)=20.8
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the 1 for?(attribute,1)

Comment: ` TRUNCATE(X,D)`
Returns the number X, truncated to D decimal places.

so 1 is the value `D` i.e. number truncated to 1 decimal place

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports lots of [comparison operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html), like `>=` and `<`, which should be combined to get you the range you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it by just comparing

```
select * from table where atribute = 20.8
```

In your case do a query like

```
select * from table where atribute >= 20.75 and atribute < 20.85
```

That should do it